# How to upload to FTP

Tags: c#, ftp

> I wanted to know how I can upload a file to an ftp but if that file
>   already exists I wanted to override that file.

This is the code I used to upload the file to ftp:

```
var ip = myDllConfigAppSettings1.Settings["testeIP"].Value;
                            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ip + nomecompleto + ".txt");
                            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

                            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("test", "teste123");

                            StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader(arquivo.FullName);
                            byte[] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());
                            sourceStream.Close();
                            request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;

                            Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
                            requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
                            requestStream.Close();

                            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

                            MessageBox.Show("Arquivo " + arquivo.Name + " foi enviado com sucesso. " + response.StatusDescription);

                            response.Close();
```

But this code does not overwrite the file that already exists.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to overwrite file via FTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22906341/how-to-overwrite-file-via-ftp)

Comment: `byte[] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());`. You should re-think this too. Open a `FileStream`, Read a `Buffer`, Write the `Buffer` to the Request Stream while the `FileStream` returns a number of bytes read > 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
            // connect with ftp-server
            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                // open connection with connection-strings
                client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(this.Username, this.Password);
                // upload zip-file on server
                client.UploadFile("ftp://localhost/"+ cleanFileName, WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile,zipFileName);
            }
```

Comment: What is your 'zipfilename' ?

Comment: it is the name of my file (path where my file is stored e.g. "C:\User\myFile.txt" ). This is the file wich I will upload on my FTP-Server